# WMWare Player 12.5: forward and back keys of Logitech mouse not working

Tags: mouse, vmware-player, logitech-mouse

I am currently using VMWare Player 12 (free edition) on Windows 10 Pro x64 as host and guest system, and a Logitech M510 mouse as input device. My problem is that inside the guest-system, my "side" buttons (forward and back) do not work in any program.

I already googled for similar problems, and found out that some additional entries in the VMX-file are necessary:

```
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
mouse.vusb.enable = "TRUE"
mouse.vusb.useBasicMouse = "FALSE"
```

However, even when I add these settings, the additional buttons do not work, so I guess VMWare must have changed something additional.

Does anybody know a solution to this in newer versions of VMWare Player? I found a similar thread at the VMWare forums concerning the latest version of VMWare workstation, without a solution, so I guess this affects the latest player and workstation versions unfortunately.

Comment: Did you fully power-off the virtual machine and power it back on after making those changes to the .vmx file?  Those settings should allow the mouse to connect to the VM as a USB device (which would allow all buttons to work, provided that any necessary device drivers are also installed in the guest).

Comment: OF course I completely shut down the VM, I always do when making changes to the VMX file. It didn't work anyway unfortunatley.